# Find index of a number in an array between two elemen

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following code,

```
const arr = [0, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22];

const number = 13;

let index;
```

I would like to find the index of `number` where the following condition apply.

`number` >= to the array element but smaller than the next element.

For example here `index` would be 3 as `arr[3]` is bigger than 10 but smaller than 14

I am unsure if there is an array method to find that solution.

Any help I’d appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findIndex

```js
const arr = [0, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22];
const number = 13;

let index = arr.findIndex((element, index) => number >= element && number < arr[index + 1])

console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [0, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22];

const number = 13;

let index;

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const prevNum = arr[i - 1]
  const currNum = arr[i];
  if (prevNum <= number && currNum > number) {
    index = i - 1;
  }
}

console.log(index)
```